# Exception using Google.GData.Apps : The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-admin-sdk, google-provisioning-api, google-client-login

I am using google provisioning api on my website. I want to authenticate user using AppsService class.

```
AppsService service = new AppsService("domain", "admin username", "admin password");
UserEntry user = service.RetrieveUser("username");
```

But it throws exception: Execution of request failed: https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/pmu.mygbiz.com/user/2.0/username

> InnerException is: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server
>   Unavailable.

It was working before 6 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

[ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps) (login and password) was deprecated as of April 20, 2012 and turned off on May 26 2015.   This code will not longer work you need to switch to using Oauth2.

I think you need to switch to the admin directory api as well

```
PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1
```

**Update code:**

I can give you some sample code but I cant test it 100% I don't have an apps domain.

**helper class:**

```
class AuthenticationHelper
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Authenticate to Google Using Oauth2
        /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientId">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="clientSecret">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="userName">A string used to identify a user.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DirectoryService AuthenticateOauth(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)
        {

            // There are a lot of scopes check here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing
            string[] scopes = new string[] {
                    DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroup  ,  // Manage your Groups
                    DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser   // Manage users 
                    };

            try
            {
                // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
                UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                    , scopes
                                                                    , userName
                                                                    , CancellationToken.None
                                                                    , new FileDataStore("Daimto.AdminSDK.Auth.Store")).Result;



                DirectoryService service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Directory API Sample",
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                return null;

            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Authenticating to Google using a Service account
        /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceAccountEmail">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="keyFilePath">Location of the Service account key file downloaded from Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DirectoryService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string keyFilePath)
        {

            // check the file exists
            if (!File.Exists(keyFilePath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An Error occurred - Key file does not exist");
                return null;
            }

            // There are a lot of scopes check here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing
            string[] scopes = new string[] {
                    DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroup  ,  // Manage your Groups
                    DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser   // Manage users 
                    };

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            try
            {
                ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                    {
                        Scopes = scopes
                    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                // Create the service.
                DirectoryService service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Directory API Sample",
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                return null;

            }
        }
    }
```

**authenticate :**

```
 var service = AuthenticationHelper.AuthenticateOauth("xxxxx-d0vpdthl4ms0soutcrpe036ckqn7rfpn.apps.googleusercontent.com", "NDmluNfTgUk6wgmy7cFo64RV", "userID");
```

**Make a request:**

```
    try
    {
        var userList = service.Users.List();
        userList.MaxResults = 10;
        userList.Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);


    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

code ripped from sample project [Google-Dotnet-Samples](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples) / [admin Directory](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Admin-Directory)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to find code for it(admin directory api) in asp.net but i not getting any solution. Do you have any link for it?

Comment: I don't have a tutorial for this api,  You can try and follow my Google Analytics tutorial the code above should get you started, the tutorial will explain what its doing.   http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-authentication-csharp/   I cant test it more because I don't have a domain account.